# is there anyway to remove some values from createCriteria groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

Hi I was just wondering is there any way to subtract the values from groovy createCriteria list?

say i have a list like

```
results = c.list(max:3) {
                createAlias('drama', 'd', CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN)
                ac{
                    eq( 'cat', cat )
                }

                or {
                    eq('d.ps',Js.xxx)
                    eq('sr',Js.ac)
}-eq('d.cr',true)}
```

Currently I get all the results where d.cr=true, but I wanted to get rid of those values from original results set.
is there anyway to do the above substraction?

Comment: Are you saying that you would not like d.cr in the result set, or are you attempting to make the query not have d.cr = true (which would be the same as saying d.cr = false)?

Comment: isn't it basically working, when you remove the ``-`` there and say just ``eq('d.cr', false)`` (or ``ne('d.cr', true)``)?  on that level the line gets AND-ed to your query and should return the desired result.  or do you even want to influence the ``max``? in that case i'd remove them in groovy.  something like ``results = c.list{...}.findAll( !it.d.cr }``

Comment: On the current result set (without d.cr=true) it includes values that are in(d.cr,true) i simply wanted to remove that set from the result set! Further i dont want to have (d.cr,false) on my result set.

Comment: Currently I get only the results where  d.cr=true